# I can't place frames the way i want in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Good afternoon!
Right to the heart of the matter: I have a window, it has a tab, and in it I want to place three main frames. One on the left, one on the right and one on the bottom. It is impossible to arrange the first two at the same level horizontally. Screenshots of how it looks now, and how I would like to see it, are attached.
Here is a part of the code:

```
my_notebook.tab(current_tab, text=gang.name)
frame_left = Frame(current_tab, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)  # THIS IS TOP LEFT FRAME
frame_left.pack(anchor=NW)
frame_right = Frame(current_tab, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE)  # THIS IS TOP RIGHT FRAME
frame_right.pack(anchor=NE)
f11 = LabelFrame(current_tab, borderwidth=2, pady=5, text="Founders", font=('arial', 14), relief=GROOVE) #  THIS IS BOTTOM FRAME
f11.pack(anchor=S, fill=BOTH)
```

[NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjxy.png)
[IN DREAMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRIt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order that you call `pack` matters, because the packer will place widgets on the side of *remaining* space. Once you put something on the left or right,  it takes up the entire side, top to bottom.

The other problem is that you're not specifying the side, so the side defaults to "top". You need to use a side of "left" or "right" for the two at the top, and "bottom" for the one on the bottom.

The solution is to first pack the frame that is on the bottom, so that it takes up the entire bottom. When you pack widgets to the left or right they will take up the left or the right above the frame that is on the bottom.

Personally I find that grouping your calls to `pack` together makes solving layout problems much easier than interspersing them with the code that creates the widgets, like in the following example.

```
f11.pack(side="bottom", fill=BOTH)
frame_left.pack(side="left", fill=BOTH)
frame_right.pack(side="right", fill=BOTH)
```

For the canonical description of how the packer works, see [The packer algorithm](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm#M27) in the official tcl/tk manual pages.

Comment: And what must be done if you want to place the left, right next to the bottom at left right and another left right on top of it? No ... I don't want to get this question answered. I want only to point out how much you  have to explain about it. You can avoid it using the concept of the grid.

Comment: @Claudio: both `grid` and `pack` require some level of understanding to be able to use them correctly. grid requires it's own extra bit of explaining to use it effectively (row and column weights, for example, and how to use the `uniform` option)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

**Use the tkinter .grid (manager) instead of using `.pack`**

and arrange your frames in the 2x2 grid putting the third into the grid spanning two rows.

Just check out the tkinter documentation for how to use the grid manager for appropriate commands.

The advantage of using the grid manager in tkinter is that you have full control over placing your frames. You can even define empty columns and rows of chosen size in order to achieve visible spacing between the placed elements.

**Using .pack is convenient, but can lead because of its automated and from user hidden logic to confusion. If it won't lead to confusion your question won't be here.** Even if the most experienced tkinter poster here on stackoverflow recommends in his answer re-arranging the order of the pack commands, I would suggest to use the grid manager for more complex layouts and the pack manager only for the very simple ones.

Below the code demonstrating placing widgets into the grid:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
L_l = tkinter.Label(root, text="LEFT")
L_r = tkinter.Label(root, text="RIGHT")
L_b = tkinter.Label(root, text="BOTTOM")
L_l.grid(row=1, column=1)
L_r.grid(row=1, column=2)
L_b.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
# all the possible .grid() parameter: 
#   column, columnspan, in, ipadx, ipady, padx, pady, row, rowspan, sticky
root.mainloop()
```

creating:

[image]

Changing the padx, pady parameter of the .grid() to:

```
L_l.grid(row=1, column=1,  padx=50, pady=20)
L_r.grid(row=1, column=2,  padx=50, pady=20)
L_b.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=30)
```

gives:

[image]

adding the code for appropriate values impacting the size of rows/columns respectively to others:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(   1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
# other possible parameter here is minsize= expressed in pixels
# to prevent too small sizes when shrinking tkinter window
```

will result in better response of the layout to resizing the tkinter window as shown in the picture below:

[image]

If you want that columns have same width even if sizes of the widgets in these columns are not the same use:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="groupID")
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform="groupID")
# groupID identifies columns which should be same width
```

(Same is valid concerning rows)

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden logic"? The packer algorithm is documented.

Comment: _" I would suggest to use the grid manager for more complex layouts and the pack manager only for the very simple ones."_ - this is good advice. However, I would argue that the OP's situation is a very good example of a simple layout that `pack` excels at solving.

Comment: At the first glance at the by you proposed code I expect the left and right frames being placed below the first placed frame. At the second glance I see the `side="bottom"` parameter, but still wonder why the `anchor=S` didn't work and why f11 have to be placed first. Sure ... the algorithm is documented ... but the confusion is also there which won't maybe occur while using the grid manager. This is the reason I prefer the grid over pack for complex designs as the concept of a grid appeals to me more than coping with south, left, margin, bottom, etc. As a newbie I see things experts don't.

Comment: `anchor=S` works as documented. First, the packer will allocate a side of the remaining empty space. Once this space has been allocated, the anchor specifies how the widget is in that space. So if you put something at the top (by virtue of not specifying an explicit side) the packer will allocate space at the top. Then, the widget will be placed at the bottom portion of the allocated space.

Comment: It is like comparing Python to C or Assembler. The grid concept is well known and tables are used everywhere. Thanks for explaining the concepts of the pack manager. I think it's a question of personal preference. If I want a quick shot ... I use pack as with grid manager I have to think a bit before using it, but profit afterwards. Thanks for revoking the downvote.

Comment: I would argue there are aspects of `grid` that are also non-intuitive. For example, people who ask questions here constantly forget to add weight to rows and columns. The bottom line is that you should read the documentation and then choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: I disagree that it's like comparing python to C or assembler. It's more like comparing python to ruby.

Comment: Yes, you are right ... I just over-exaggerated the differences.

Comment: In your example you've failed to set a weight for any rows or columns, which means your UI won't be responsive to changes in the window size.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Have incorporated it into my answer.